# Dustin's Grrrr - Fake or real?

Tags: sound-effects, stranger-things

Dustin in *Stranger Things* performs a "grrrr" at multiple occasions.

The sound is weirdly pleasing. I dont think anyone else could produce the same sound. One could argue that Dustin's voice is also different from average humans, maybe that could explain how it can be real.....

Is the sound completely real or the magic of sound engineering?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't really understand why you say that people can't make a similar sound, it's just a regular growl/purr. He does it [here](http://www.emresanli.com/video/?id=1j-noIF7ZHY):

Anyway, the actor is an [ex-musical star](https://thedebrief.co.uk/news/celebrity/stranger-things-dustin-singing/), so maybe that's why you find it more appealing than usual. He also has a lisp, which might or might not influence the way he makes that particular sound.